# three monitors, one is very slow

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, performance

I have three 23" monitors attached to 2 cards:

1. Geforce GT 220 (1gb)
2. Geforce 8400 GS (512mb)

My System is quad core (Q8300 @ 2.50Ghz)
6GB Ram
64-bit windows 7 professional

I have 2 monitors connected to the GT 220 and they work perfectly.
I have 1 monitor (was hoping to attach another one) to the 8400

The monitor atatched to the 8400 is quite slow and jerky.

What can i do to improve the performance?
I disabled aero theme, didn't make much difference (if any)

Comment: What kind of interface are you using for the 8400? It is a PCI, or PCIe in a 1x slot, or anything like that?

Comment: i had to go pci as i had no available pci-e slots

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest drivers from The NVIDIA website? I'm struggling to think of why it'd be slow and jerky in the first place. I'm using two much less powerful cards (one of them is a NVIDIA inbuilt to the mobo!) to tri-monitor on this machine and it's fine.